# Difference between for and while loop(not in terms of syntax and efficiency)

Tags: java, c

What is the need for using the `while` loop when we can iterate without using  `while`? Is there something that cannot be done without `while`?

Comment: You can do everything with `if()` and `goto`. Do you want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing that `while` can do that you wouldn't be able to do with `for`. In fact,

```
while (xxxxxxx) {
}
```

can be replaced mechanically with

```
for (; xxxxxxx ;) {
}
```

and the code would work exactly the same.

The only reason for having the `while` loop as well is better readability of your code.